# Merging cells in an Excel-like table with PyQt5 not working as intended

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I'm trying to make an Excel-like table in a GUI application with PyQt5. I'm struggling to add a merge/unmerge feature.
After adding a few print statements, I noticed that merging a first group of cells will work, but when I try to merge a second group of cells, it will for some reason select only one cell (even though I've selected multiple) and the merge will not be successful.
Once I unmerge the first group of cells, I can merge another group again, but thats it, just one group.

Has anyone ever encountered this issue or know a fix? I can't seem to find any helpful posts on stackoverflow or youtube.

I attempted to make it so the entire row would be selected.
In that case, I was able to merge multiple different groups of rows.
But I want it to be cells, like in Excel. And that doesn't work.

Adding `self.tableWidget.clearSelection()` didn't seem to help either.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QEvent
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableWidget, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QPushButton


class ExcelLikeTable(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.mergeButton = None
        self.unmergeButton = None
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Excel-like Table with PyQt5")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)

        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(10)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels([f'Column {chr(65+i)}' for i in range(10)])
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(1)

        self.tableWidget.clearSelection()
        self.tableWidget.setSelectionMode(QTableWidget.ContiguousSelection)
        self.tableWidget.setSelectionBehavior(QTableWidget.SelectItems)

        self.mergeButton = QPushButton("Merge Cells")
        self.unmergeButton = QPushButton("Unmerge Cells")
        self.mergeButton.clicked.connect(self.mergeCells)
        self.unmergeButton.clicked.connect(self.unmergeCells)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.mergeButton)
        layout.addWidget(self.unmergeButton)

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        centralWidget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.tableWidget.installEventFilter(self)

    def mergeCells(self):
        if not self.tableWidget.selectedRanges():
            print("No cells selected for merging.")
            return

        selectedRange = self.tableWidget.selectedRanges()[0]
        topRow, leftColumn = selectedRange.topRow(), selectedRange.leftColumn()
        rowCount, columnCount = selectedRange.rowCount(), selectedRange.columnCount()

        print(
            f"Selected range - Top Row: {topRow}, Left Column: {leftColumn}, Row Count: {rowCount}, Column Count: {columnCount}")

        if rowCount == 1 and columnCount == 1:
            print("Only a single cell selected, no merge performed.")
            return

        self.tableWidget.setSpan(topRow, leftColumn, rowCount, columnCount)
        print(
            f"Merge completed from Cell {chr(65 + leftColumn)}{topRow + 1} to Cell {chr(65 + leftColumn + columnCount - 1)}{topRow + rowCount}")

    def unmergeCells(self):
        for i in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
            for j in range(self.tableWidget.columnCount()):
                self.tableWidget.setSpan(i, j, 1, 1)

    def addRow(self):
        rowCount = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(rowCount)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress and event.key() == Qt.Key_Return:
            currentRow = self.tableWidget.currentRow()
            currentColumn = self.tableWidget.currentColumn()
            if currentRow == self.tableWidget.rowCount() - 1:
                self.addRow()
            self.tableWidget.setCurrentCell(currentRow + 1, currentColumn)
            return True
        return super(ExcelLikeTable, self).eventFilter(source, event)

    def debugPrintCellSpans(self):
        print("Debugging cell spans:")
        for i in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
            for j in range(self.tableWidget.columnCount()):
                rowSpan = self.tableWidget.rowSpan(i, j)
                colSpan = self.tableWidget.columnSpan(i, j)
                if rowSpan > 1 or colSpan > 1:
                    print(f"Cell at ({i+1}, {chr(65+j)}) has row span: {rowSpan}, column span: {colSpan}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = ExcelLikeTable()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by the name, [selectedRanges](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#selectedRanges) returns a *list of ranges*, but the docs do not state under what precise circumstances multiple ranges will occur. It seems that after a merge, *every cell in the subsequent selection* forms a separate range, but whether this behaviour is as intended, or a bug, is unclear. Whatever the case may be, the behaviour of [selectedIndexes](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#selectedIndexes) is much more intuitive, so it would seem best to use that instead.

I have shown how to fix your example using the selected indexes below. It appears that clearing the spans of the currently selected cells *first* works best, as otherwise it may result in rather confusing nested spans.

```py
class ExcelLikeTable(QMainWindow):
    ...
    def unmergeCells(self):
        self.tableWidget.clearSpans()

    def mergeCells(self):
        selection = self.tableWidget.selectedIndexes()

        if not selection:
            print("No cells selected for merging.")
            return

        if len(selection) == 1:
            print("Only a single cell selected, no merge performed.")
            return

        for index in selection:
            row, column = index.row(), index.column()
            if (self.tableWidget.rowSpan(row, column) > 1 or
                self.tableWidget.columnSpan(row, column) > 1):
                self.tableWidget.setSpan(row, column, 1, 1)

        # clearing the spans may have changed the selection
        selection = sorted(self.tableWidget.selectedIndexes())

        topRow, leftColumn = selection[0].row(), selection[0].column()
        bottomRow, rightColumn = selection[-1].row(), selection[-1].column()
        rowCount = bottomRow - topRow + 1
        columnCount = rightColumn - leftColumn + 1

        print(
            f"Selected range - Top Row: {topRow}, Left Column: {leftColumn}, Row Count: {rowCount}, Column Count: {columnCount}")

        self.tableWidget.setSpan(topRow, leftColumn, rowCount, columnCount)
        print(
            f"Merge completed from Cell {chr(65 + leftColumn)}{topRow + 1} to Cell {chr(65 + leftColumn + columnCount - 1)}{topRow + rowCount}")
```